# Using an extension to populate a combobox from an enum?

Tags: c#, winforms, lambda

Currently I have the following extension to read the `Description` attribute from an enum:

```
public static T GetAttributeOfType<T>(this Enum enumVal) where T : System.Attribute
{
    var type = enumVal.GetType();
    var memInfo = type.GetMember(enumVal.ToString());
    var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false);

    return (attributes.Length > 0) ? (T)attributes[0] : null;
}
```

Then in my various forms, I have the following code to populate a combobox from an enum:

```
var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))
               .Cast<MyEnum>()
               .ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
               .ToList();

cbo.DataSource = list;
cbo.DisplayMember = "Value";
cbo.ValueMember = "Key";
```

The above code works fine. However I would like to move the code in a second extension method similar to this:

```
public static Dictionary<T, string> FromEnum<T>(this ComboBox cbo)  where T: struct, IConvertible
{
    var list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
                    .Cast<T>()
                    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => v.GetAttributeOfType<DescriptionAttribute>().Description)
                    .ToList();

    cbo.DataSource = list;
    cbo.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cbo.ValueMember = "Key";
}
```

But the above code doesn't compile. I get the following errors:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type

and

> The type or namespace name 'DescriptionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is it possible have this second extension method working properly?

Comment: You don't need create CustomAttribute, just use [DescriptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Peyman Can you elaborate?

Comment: I added answer, please check that, and if it's not clear, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
public enum SampleEnum
{
    [Description("Some Value")]
    First = 1,

    [Description("Some Value")]      
    Second = 2,

    [Description("Some Value")]      
    Third = 3,
}

public static IList<ListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this Enum @enum, string firstOption = null)
{
        var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList<T>();
        var list = items.Select(x => new ListItem() { Text = Enum.Parse(typeof(T), x.ToString()).GetDescription(), Value = x.ToString() }).ToList();
        if (firstOption != null)
        {
            list.Insert(0, new ListItem() { Text = firstOption, Value = "" });
        }

        return list;
}
```

And use like this:

```
SampleEnum.First.ToSelectList();
```

**UPDATING**

Sorry I forgot to put GetDescrption extension:

```
public static string GetDescription(this object obj)
{
        var fi = obj.GetType().GetField(obj.ToString());
        var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;

        return obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The first line must be changed to: `var items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList<T>()`. But still I get compilation error on `GetDescription()`.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Sorry, I forgot to put GetDescription extension method, please check the updated code